# Finding remainder mod involving exponent and division involving huge numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I need a fast algorithm to evaluate the following

```
((a^n-1)/(a-1)) % p
```

Both `a` and `n` are nearly equal but less to 10^6 and `p` is a fixed prime number (let's say `p=1000003`). I need to compute it under 1 second. I am using python. Wolfram Mathematica [computes it instantly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Mod[%28%2810%5E6%29%5E%2810%5E6%29%20-%201%29%2F%2810%5E6%20-%201%29%2C%201000003]). It takes 35.2170000076 seconds with following code

```
print (((10**6)**(10**6)-1)/((10**6)-1))%1000003
```

If that denominator `a-1` were not present, I could group the powers into smaller order and use the relation `a*b (mod c) = (a (mod c) * b (mod c)) (mod c)` but denominator is present.

How to evaluate this with a fast algorithm? No numpy/scipy are available.

**UPDATE::** Here is the final code I came up with

```
def exp_div_mod(a, n, p):
    r = pow(a, n, p*(a-1)) - 1
    r = r - 1 if r == -1 else r
    return r/(a-1)
```

Comment: you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm to find the inverse `1/(a-1) mod p`; then apply the last identity you wrote.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'll try and let you know.

Comment: The [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) module has a function that can compute modulus inverse: `gmpy.divm` "returns x such that b*x==a modulo m, or else raises a ZeroDivisionError exception if no such value x exists". With `a`, `n` & `p` as in the OP, `(pow(a,n,p)-1)*gmpy.divm(1,a-1,p) % p` returns 444446.

Comment: Of course, gmpy isn't necessary if you do a little bit of algebra, as in samgak's answer. :)

Comment: `r = r - 1 if r == -1 else r` in your update is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(((a ** n) - 1) / (a-1)) % p

can be rewritten as

(((a ** n) - 1) % ((a-1)*p)) / (a-1)

This part:

(((a ** n) - 1) % ((a-1)*p))

can be computed by calculating this:

((a ** n) % ((a-1)*p))

and then adjusting for the -1 afterwards.

Raise a by to the nth power and mod by ((a-1)*p). This can be done using the Python pow() function. Then adjust for the -1 and divide by a-1.

Using the pow() function and passing a modulo value is faster than computing the full exponent and then taking the modulo, because the modulo can be applied to the partial products at each stage of the calculation, which stops the value from getting too large (10<sup>6</sup> to the power of 10<sup>6</sup> has 6 million decimal digits, with a modulo applied at each step the values never have to grow larger than the size of the modulo - about 13 digits in this example).

Code:

```
def exp_div_mod(a, n, p):
    m = p * (a - 1)
    return ((pow(a, n, m) - 1) % m) // (a - 1);

print exp_div_mod((10**6), (10**6), 1000003)
```

output:

```
444446
```

Note: this approach only works if a, n and p are integers.

Comment: Nice! But you don't need that loop: the built-in Python `pow` function takes a modulus as an optional 3rd argument. So you can do `m = p * (a - 1); x = ((pow(a, n, m) - 1) % m) // (a - 1)`

Comment: @NiklasB.: Why won't it work? Note that `((a ** n) - 1) / (a-1)` is an integer (the sum of a geometric progression). Let `q/b` be an integer, with `q/b = k*p + r`. Then `q=k*(p*b)+(r*b)`

Comment: @NiklasB. FWIW, I just tested samgak's algorithm against `(a**n - 1) / (a - 1)) % p` for 10000 randomly chosen 1 < a, n, p <10000, with p prime. There were no failures.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't read the answer properly. Nice trick extending the modulus, pretty clever :)

Comment: You could also shorten the second to last lines of your function to `return (pow(a, n, m) - 1) % m / (a-1)`, but that's just a matter of preference

Comment: @NiklasB. No worries. And I did mention that optimization in my first comment. :)

Comment: looks like you changed your code now :) I have one final question. what does that `//` do?

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate: `//` is integer division. It's not _really_ necessary here, but I think it's good to be explicit that we're not doing float division.

Answer (score 3):

(*a*<sup>*n*</sup>−1) ⁄ (*a*−1) is the sum from *i* = 0 to *n*−1 of *a*<sup>*i*</sup>.

Computing the latter mod *p* is straightforward, based on the following:

let *F*(*a*, *n*) be Σ(*i*=0..*n-1*){*a*<sup>*i*</sup>} if *n* > 0, otherwise 0.

Now:

1. *F*(*a*,*n*) = *a*×*F*(*a*,*n*−1) + 1
2. *F*(*a*,2*n*) = (*a*+1)×*F*(*a*<sup>2</sup>,n)

The second identity is the divide-and-conquer recursion.

Since both of these only involve addition and multiplication, we can compute them mod *p* without needing an integer type larger than *a*×*p* by distributing the modulus operation. (See code below.)

With just the first recursion, we can code an iterative solution:

```
def sum_of_powers(a, n, p):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(n): sum = (a * sum + 1) % p
  return sum
```

Using the divide-and-conquer recursion as well, we arrive at something not much more complicated:

```
def sum_of_powers(a, n, p):
  if n % 2 == 1:
    return (a * sum_of_powers(a, n-1, p) + 1) % p
  elif n > 0:
    return ((a + 1) * sum_of_powers(a * a % p, n // 2, p)) % p
  else:
    return 0
```

The first solution returns in less than a second with n == 10<sup>6</sup>. The second one returns instantly, even with n as large as 10<sup>9</sup>.

Comment: Can you do it without a loop? Summing a million or so mod powers in a loop isn't exactly fast.

Comment: @PM2Ring There is a trick where you seperate the odd and even terms and reuse the sum of even summands to compute the sum of the odd ones in O(1), yielding an algorithm that uses only O(log n) additions and multiplications

Comment: @pm2ring: if you sum a^i%p startimg with i=0, each term requires "only" a multiply and a mod (by taking advantage of the value of the previous term); you never need to compute a power. A million such computations can be done easily in a second on modern hardwaree. But NiklasB's suggestion is even faster

Comment: @NiklasB. Interesting! I _think_ I see how that divide-and-conquer approach would work in O(log n).

Comment: @rici trust me, I tried this before I posted answer question here. I considered the method proposed by Nicholas B but found it too much to code it up.

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate: I trust that you tried it, but I don't believe your try was effective. Also, you overestimate the complexity of NiklasB's solution, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: Upvoted, because this works whether or not p is prime.

Comment: A different recurrence relation (in which the "a" arg is constant) for the even case is: F(a, 2n) = F(a, n) * ((a-1) * F(a, n) + 2), because (a-1)*F(a, n) = a^(n+1) - 1. Obviously you have to be careful not to evaluate F(a, n) twice though.

Comment: @PaulHankin Nice catch, I like it

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply by the [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `p - 1`. Due to Fermat's little theorem, you have *x<sup>p-2</sup> · x ≡ x<sup>p-1</sup> ≡ 1 (mod p)* for all *0 < x < p*, so you don't even need extended Euclid to compute the inverse, just the `pow` function from standard Python:

```
(pow(a, n, p) - 1) * pow(a - 1, p - 2, p) % p
```

The algorithm has time complexity *(log p)* because [square-and-multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is used.

Comment: I guess you mean the inverse of `a-1`, not `p-1`.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your first approach, could you write some math for it? I am aware of Fermat's theorem, but after it ??

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate You can divide by a number *x* modulo a prime by multiplying with the modular inverse *x^(-1)*. Typically you would use extended Euclid's algorithm to compute the inverse, but in the case of a prime modulus the inverse is just *x^(p-2)*, due to Fermat's theorem

Comment: I understand the other answer, but still, I am not getting it mathematically. x is the modular inverse of x^(p-2) due to Fermat, but how is [this relation](http://i.imgur.com/asQrMzk.png?1) true?

Comment: Pity we can't use LaTeX here, like on [SE.Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: @PM2Ring still, we can use screenshots from M.SE

Comment: @dread_cat_pirate Your formula is different from what I suppose. I'm saying that *x / y = x * y^(-1)* for arbitrary x, y with y != 0. In this case, *(a^n-1)/(a-1) = a^n - 1 * (a-1)^(-1)*